# What does this symbol refer to?

Tags: symbol

[image]

What is the symbol that is below the C1 capacitor and R1 resistor. Is it the symbol of grounding?

Comment: This question has little to recomend it - it doesn't seem that you did much work yourself to find an answer, and the answer is rather trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol represents signal ground. This ground is often connected to the usual ground of a device, commonly known as "earth". However if a system is very sensitive the two grounds cannot simply be connected, but require a thorough engeneering approach and a good ground able to handle high currents.

More info on the grounding types:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_(electricity)#Electronics

Comment: I think ground is usually represented using the vertical line connecting with a series of horizontal lines in a triangular shape symbol.  Ground, 0V, earth and equipotential level may be synonymous in some circuits/applications but there are subtle or critical differences in others.

Comment: The symbol shown is signal ground. The series of horizontal lines forming a triangular shape is circuit ground, and the horizontal line with vertical lines coming off of it (that looks like a fork) is earth ground.

Answer (score 6):

It means **Equipotential level**. Often used, in CAD, for analog ground or signal ground. 
See IEEE STANDARD 315-1975 - "IEEE Standard for Graphic Symbols for Electrical and Electronics Diagrams (Including Reference Designation Letters)"

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Gound or zero potential depending on your application.